# Redirect url if slug does not match

Tags: django, redirect, slug

I want to use the same url model as SO. The lookup is done through the id number but if the wrong slug is in the link than a redirect is thrown to the correct page.

example: 
questions/4787731/whatever will redirect to questions/4787731/canonical-links-and-301-redirect-if-url-doesnt-match-slug. 
My current code does the lookup through the id but does not redirect in case of a bad slug.
example:
entities/12786676/whatever should redirect to /entities/12786676/yellow-and-green-tree/. I do get the content of the page correctly but I want also the url to be redirected to avoid bad links.
Here is the code:

views:

```
class EntityRedirectDetailView(RedirectView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        slug=self.kwargs.get('slug', None)
        entity = EntitiesNew.objects.get(pk=pk)
        self.url = '/entities/%s/%s' % (entity.pk, entity.slug)
        return super(EntityRedirectDetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(context_object_name = 'entities_list', queryset=EntitiesNew.objects.order_by('-id_number')[:500]), name='entities'),  
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.EntityRedirectDetailView.as_view(), name='entities-redirect'),  
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)(?:/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+))?/$', DetailView.as_view( model=EntitiesNew, context_object_name="entity"), name="entities-detail"),
]
```

thanks

Comment: Your second pattern matches if there is only a pk in the URL, because it's followed by the `$`, so it will never match any URL with a slug, correct or not. What you could do is override the `get` in the DetailView of the third pattern, and redirect when the slug is incorrect.

Comment: thanks Paulo, you are right the second pattern is redirecting only a pk match thus there is no redirection if the slug is wrong... can you please show me what exactly do you mean by overriding the get method? I tryed with this but with no success... if slug != entity.slug():
        return redirect(entity, permanent=True) ... is something wrong with this code?

Comment: That's the general idea, but you are calling `entity.slug`, which I suppose is a typo. You are also redirecting to `entity`, and I don't have enough information to know if that's right. Do you have a `get_absolute_url` method in that model? You could also redirect to 'entities-detail' and pass the arguments.

Comment: yes I do have get_absolute_url as so: def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('entities:entities-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk, 'slug':self.slug})

Comment: That seems correct then. Sorry for another obvious question, but did you remember to edit `urls.py` to use the new view instead of the `DetailView` in you question? In any case, it might help if you edit your question and add the full view for the third pattern.

Comment: sorry I don't understand exactly what you mean about the urls.py edit... In regards to the third pattern there is no view because I'm using generic views and DetailView.as_view is defined in the urls.py file with: model=EntitiesNew, context_object_name="entity".

Comment: Oh, I see, we're not on the same page then. My suggestion was to create a view (a DetailView) for the third pattern and override its get method. That's where you have to do it to catch the slug.

Comment: ok thanks for the help I still did not figure it out but i will try some more tomorrow.. maybe is the late hour :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to do what I wanted by overriding the get method in my EntityDetailView(Detailview) as per [Paulo Almeida](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081569/paulo-almeida)'s suggestion. Here is the final code.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.EntityRedirectDetailView.as_view(), name='entities-redirect'), 
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', views.EntityDetailView.as_view(), name="entities-detail"),
```

views.py

```
class EntityRedirectDetailView(RedirectView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        slug=self.kwargs.get('slug', None)
        entity = EntitiesNew.objects.get(pk=pk)
        self.url = '/entities/%s/%s' % (entity.pk, entity.slug)
        return super(EntityRedirectDetailView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

class EntityDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    """
        A DetailView which redirects to the absolute_url, if necessary.
    """
    template_name = 'entities/entitiesnew_detail.html'
    queryset = EntitiesNew.objects.get_queryset()
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Return any previously-cached object
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        entity=EntitiesNew.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if getattr(self, 'entity', None):
            return self.entity
        return super(EntityDetailView, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Make sure to use the canonical URL
        self.entity = self.get_object()
        obj_url = self.entity.get_absolute_url()
        if self.request.path != obj_url:
            return http.HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(obj_url)
        return super(EntityDetailView, self).get(*args, **kwargs);
```

in models.py I have the get_absoulte_url:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('entities:entities-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk, 'slug':self.slug})
```

and in the template:
{% url 'entities:entities-detail' entitiesnew.pk entitiesnew.slug %}